# Python: Progressbar during image import

Tags: python, image, import, progress-bar

I have a Python Script, which has to import very large image-files (.tiff, ca. 3GB).
Is there a way to display a progressbar in the command line?
I haven't found a way to measure the progress of an import except for text files.

My current function looks like this:

```
from skimage import io

def import_tiff(filename):
    im = io.imread(filename)
    return im
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course it's possible. You could print `.`

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit on that?
I would import an image with `im = io.imread(filename)`
How would I incorporate the progress bar?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. Say what you've tried. See [ask].

Comment: Are you using [scikit](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)? I'm not sure there's a way of doing it synchronously.

Comment: This is my current function:

from skimage import io

def import_tiff(filename):
    im = io.imread(filename)
    return im